# ELK exporting logs

Tags: java, mongodb, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

i have to do a dashboard containing statisitcs about the different exception for diffrent micro-services for a big project so i'm asked to export all the logs from kibana to insert them in mongo DB but i don't know what to use to do that please help

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend elasticdump.

> https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump

I use it for moving data between servers but I think you could use it for mongoDB too if you first export the data to file.